# Making use of ReflectionTestUtils to mock a static class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, spring-test

I am writing unit test for a class which makes use of the static class *ProcessTimer*. To be precise, *ProcessTimer.startTimer()*.

I am looking for a way to mock this call. I have used plain ReflectionUtils and PowerMock before, but I am wondering if I could do this with ReflectionTestUtils which comes from Spring.

If possible, I could remove the PowerMock dependencies and rewrite few other tests too. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Dependency injection?

Answer (score 4):

`ReflectionTestUtils` is not for mocking. Rather, it is only for setting/reading non-public fields and invoking non-public methods.

If you want to *mock* what is returned by a `static` method you will have to use a dedicated mocking framework for that -- for example, something like PowerMock as you mentioned.

Regards,

Sam (*author of `ReflectionTestUtils`*)